# Artistdata.com RSS Feed parsing works locally but not on production server

Tags: php, rss, simplexml, file-get-contents

I've been trying for the past couple of days to figure out why my code works perfectly locally but fails when deployed on a production server.

My local testing environment is the latest MAMP on a 10.7.2 Lion iMac.

Basically I need to fetch certain XML RSS data from Artistdata.com in order to insert it into a simple PHP-driven, non-CMS website I'm working on.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>RSS FEED Parser</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php
    ini_set('display_errors',1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
    error_reporting(-1);

    # RSS Feed parser #
    function getFeed($feed_url) {
        $content = file_get_contents($feed_url);
        $x = new SimpleXmlElement($content);

        foreach ($x->show as $showEntry) {
            echo '<div>';# date
                $newDate = new DateTime($showEntry->date);
                echo date_format($newDate, 'l, F j, Y');
            echo '</div>';# /date

            # further data fetching, totally unrelated
            # to the problem that I'm experiencing
        }
    }
?>

<!-- START FEED PARSING -->
<div id="feed-data">
    <?php getFeed('http://feeds.artistdata.com/xml.shows/artist/AR-30CA266E4BEDD78F/xml/future'); ?>
</div>
<!-- END FEED PARSING -->

</body>
</html>
```

I'm sure there are more people who had similar problems but I've yet to find a viable solution.

If you have any pointers I'd be very grateful.

EDIT: Forgot to post the errors, so here they are below

```
Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [simplexmlelement.--construct]: Entity: line 1: parser error : Space required after the Public Identifier in /home/*****/public_html/ssr/parse-feed.php on line 17

Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [simplexmlelement.--construct]: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN"> in /home/*****/public_html/ssr/parse-feed.php on line 17

Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [simplexmlelement.--construct]: ^ in /home/*****/public_html/ssr/parse-feed.php on line 17

Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [simplexmlelement.--construct]: Entity: line 1: parser error : SystemLiteral " or ' expected in /home/*****/public_html/ssr/parse-feed.php on line 17

Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [simplexmlelement.--construct]: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN"> in /home/*****/public_html/ssr/parse-feed.php on line 17

Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [simplexmlelement.--construct]: ^ in /home/*****/public_html/ssr/parse-feed.php on line 17

Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [simplexmlelement.--construct]: Entity: line 1: parser error : SYSTEM or PUBLIC, the URI is missing in /home/*****/public_html/ssr/parse-feed.php on line 17

Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [simplexmlelement.--construct]: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN"> in /home/*****/public_html/ssr/parse-feed.php on line 17

Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [simplexmlelement.--construct]: ^ in /home/*****/public_html/ssr/parse-feed.php on line 17

Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [simplexmlelement.--construct]: Entity: line 9: parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: hr line 7 and body in /home/*****/public_html/ssr/parse-feed.php on line 17

Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [simplexmlelement.--construct]: </body></html> in /home/*****/public_html/ssr/parse-feed.php on line 17

Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [simplexmlelement.--construct]: ^ in /home/*****/public_html/ssr/parse-feed.php on line 17

Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [simplexmlelement.--construct]: Entity: line 9: parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: body line 4 and html in /home/*****/public_html/ssr/parse-feed.php on line 17

Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [simplexmlelement.--construct]: </body></html> in /home/*****/public_html/ssr/parse-feed.php on line 17

Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [simplexmlelement.--construct]: ^ in /home/*****/public_html/ssr/parse-feed.php on line 17

Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [simplexmlelement.--construct]: Entity: line 10: parser error : Premature end of data in tag html line 2 in /home/*****/public_html/ssr/parse-feed.php on line 17

Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [simplexmlelement.--construct]: in /home/*****/public_html/ssr/parse-feed.php on line 17

Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [simplexmlelement.--construct]: ^ in /home/*****/public_html/ssr/parse-feed.php on line 17

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'String could not be parsed as XML' in /home/*****/public_html/ssr/parse-feed.php:17 Stack trace: #0 /home/*****/public_html/ssr/parse-feed.php(17): SimpleXMLElement->__construct('<!DOCTYPE HTML ...') #1 /home/*****/public_html/ssr/parse-feed.php(33): getFeed('http://feeds.ar...') #2 {main} thrown in /home/*****/public_html/ssr/parse-feed.php on line 17
```

**Problem solved, I was using the wrong feed, the correct one is http://artistdata.sonicbids.com/john-latini/shows/xml/future**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That XML does not look like RSS. It is an specific format defined by http://feeds.artistdata.com/_css/shows.xsd.

The error messages all say that you get an HTML (2.0) page not a XML. I can not reproduce that, I get the XML using file_get_contents().

Try to output the HTML page, maybe it has some more information.

```
echo file_get_contents('http://feeds.artistdata.com/xml.shows/artist/AR-30CA266E4BEDD78F/xml/future');
```

Comment: you've just made my day! By echoing the contents of the feed as per your suggestion, I got the link to the properly-formatted XML feed, that is, [link](http://artistdata.sonicbids.com/john-latini/shows/xml/future). Everything works beautifully now! Thanks buddy!